# Focusing on tabs opened from an existing tab (not blank, independent ones) with Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs

By default Chrome opens a new tab in the background when it's from a link in an existing tab. I'd like the focus to switch to the newly opened one automatically.

I've found two extensions, named [Tab Activate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-activate/jlmadbnpnnolpaljadgakjilggigioaj), and [Switch to New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switch-to-new-tab/lfpdoeknpnclenhlmblmenpafkbcgdbg).

However, it looks like both of them cause Chrome to try to load all open tabs when you restarted it, which is a disaster, so they're not usable. (And I broke my back to find out what extension(s) were causing it...)

I'd like to ask if there's a better solution. (The same question seems to have been asked 14 years ago, but the answers no longer seems to apply.)

Thanks,
A.

P.S. For bonus points, I'd like the new tab to open next to the current tab instead of at the end (and yes, I've seen the post about moving tabs around, but this is different).

Comment: I guess I do no understand. Chrome opens ready for use in the foreground Windows 10 and Windows 11; Kali; and Ubuntu

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean foreground when you just open a blank new tab (through the + sign on title bar, or Ctrl+T)?  Blank new tabs open in the foreground for me too. I had meant the tabs opened through a right click or Ctrl+Click on a link.  I'll try to clarify the post.  BTW, I have the latest Version 112.0.5615.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)